# else if error on Command part

Tags: if-statement, command

I can't fix this code that gives `Else` without `If`:

```
Sub aRefreshData()
If Worksheets("Control tab").Range("$I$2").Value = "OFF" Then MsgBox "Enable Connection before refresh"
Else
 ActiveWorkbook.Connections("server DB").Refresh
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. You need to add a language tag (this looks like vba), [format your code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting), and expand your explanation of what your problem is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed ":" after Else

```
Sub aRefreshData()
If Worksheets("Control tab").Range("$I$2").Value = "OFF" Then 
    MsgBox "Enable Connection before refresh"
Else:
    ActiveWorkbook.Connections("server DB").Refresh
End If
End Sub
```